# Is there any way I can get Parent company details by providing child company details?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I am looking for a way in which I can get Parent company details by providing child company details. I came across to this tool (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-org-units) while searching, and I understand that we can get details of all children for particular organization. API returns the list with all hierarchical data for a company like all children companies as well as sub-children. But we need to retrieve the details of parent company, when I will pass the information of child company. Like which company is parent/owner of a particular company.

Answer (score 0):

The [Orgunits](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/orgunits) resource has a field `parentOrgUnitId` which contains the ID of the parent orgunit. You can use the `Orgunits.get()` endpoint to get the details of that orgunit.